# How to connect to MySQL using Node-mysql in a Cucumber-JS step definition?

Tags: javascript, node-mysql, cucumberjs

I am trying to connect to a MySQL database in my Cucumber-JS stepDefinition file, using [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/), via a connection method defined in world.js.  Unfortunately it will not connect and return my query results, nor can I get it to show me an error message that will help me figure out where I am going wrong.

I have used Cucumber-JVM in the past, but am new to JavaScript and node.js.  I have created a standalone js file with the same method present (to mimic the world.js), and called that successfully from another test script (to mimic the stepDefinitions.js); it connects and returns the record happily, so this is probably down to my misunderstanding of context within JavaScript in general, or within the way Cucumber-JS uses world, perhaps...

stepDefinitons.js:

```
'use strict';

var ImportStepDefinitions = function() {

    this.World = require('../support/world.js').World;

    this.Given(/^I have a clean Magento database$/, function (callback) {
        this.connectToDatabase();
        //this.clearDatabase();
        callback();
    });

    this.When(/^I import the test data file "([^"]*)"$/, function (testDataFile, callback) {
        //this.importTestFile();
        callback.pending();
    });

    this.Then(/^an attribute set is created called "([^"]*)"$/, function (attributeSetName, callback) {
        //this.validateAttributeSet();
        callback.pending();
    });

};
module.exports = ImportStepDefinitions;
```

world.js:

```
'use strict';


var World = function World(callback) {

    var mysql = require('mysql');
    var host = 'localhost';
    var user = 'user';
    var password = 'password';
    var database = 'magento';
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: host,
        user: user,
        password: password,
        database: database
    });

    this.connectToDatabase = function () {
        connection.connect(function(err){
            if(err) {
                console.error("Connection error: " + err.stack);
                return;
            }
            console.log("Connection state 1 = ", connection);
        });

        connection.query('SELECT * FROM admin_user', function (err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) {
                console.error("Query error: " + err.stack);
                return;
            }
            console.log("ROWS ====== ", rows[0]);
            recordDetail = rows[0];
        });
        console.log("Connection state 2 = ", connection);
        connection.end();
    };

    this.clearDatabase = function(scriptName) {
        //Run import script in sql so starting with a fresh magento database
    };

    this.importTestFile = function(testFileName) {
         //Need to call import.php with file location
    };

    this.validateAttributeSet = function(attributeSetName) {
         //Use magento object (?) to check attribute set exists as expected
    };

    callback();
};

module.exports.World = World;
```

When I execute the code I get nothing back from connection.connect(), neither error or log, no record is logged out from connection.query(), and connection at 'connection state 2 =' shows (right at the bottom) a _connectCalled value of true, but a state of disconnected and a threadId of null:

```
Connection state 2 =  { domain: 
   { domain: null,
     _events: { error: [Function: handleScenarioException] },
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [],
     id: 'domain-1437457225974' },
  _events: {},
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  config: 
   { host: 'localhost',
     port: 3306,
     localAddress: undefined,
     socketPath: undefined,
     user: 'user',
     password: 'password',
     database: 'magento',
     connectTimeout: 10000,
     insecureAuth: false,
     supportBigNumbers: false,
     bigNumberStrings: false,
     dateStrings: false,
     debug: undefined,
     trace: true,
     stringifyObjects: false,
     timezone: 'local',
     flags: '',
     queryFormat: undefined,
     pool: undefined,
     ssl: false,
     multipleStatements: false,
     typeCast: true,
     maxPacketSize: 0,
     charsetNumber: 33,
     clientFlags: 455631 },
  _socket: 
   { _connecting: true,
     _hadError: false,
     _handle: 
      { fd: -1,
        reading: false,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: [Function: onread],
        onconnection: null,
        writeQueueSize: 0 },
     _parent: null,
     _host: 'localhost',
     _readableState: 
      { objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: false,
        sync: true,
        needReadable: false,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null,
        resumeScheduled: true },
     readable: false,
     domain: 
      { domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        members: [],
        id: 'domain-1437457225974' },
     _events: 
      { end: [Object],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        data: [Function],
        error: [Function],
        connect: [Object],
        timeout: [Object] },
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState: 
      { objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: true,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: false,
     destroyed: false,
     bytesRead: 0,
     _bytesDispatched: 0,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     _idleTimeout: 10000,
     _idleNext: { _idleNext: [Circular], _idlePrev: [Circular] },
     _idlePrev: { _idleNext: [Circular], _idlePrev: [Circular] },
     _idleStart: 2735419 },
  _protocol: 
   { domain: 
      { domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        members: [],
        id: 'domain-1437457225974' },
     _events: 
      { data: [Function],
        end: [Object],
        handshake: [Function],
        unhandledError: [Function],
        drain: [Function],
        enqueue: [Function] },
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     readable: true,
     writable: true,
     _config: 
      { host: 'localhost',
        port: 3306,
        localAddress: undefined,
        socketPath: undefined,
        user: 'user',
        password: 'password',
        database: 'magento',
        connectTimeout: 10000,
        insecureAuth: false,
        supportBigNumbers: false,
        bigNumberStrings: false,
        dateStrings: false,
        debug: undefined,
        trace: true,
        stringifyObjects: false,
        timezone: 'local',
        flags: '',
        queryFormat: undefined,
        pool: undefined,
        ssl: false,
        multipleStatements: false,
        typeCast: true,
        maxPacketSize: 0,
        charsetNumber: 33,
        clientFlags: 455631 },
     _connection: [Circular],
     _callback: null,
     _fatalError: null,
     _quitSequence: null,
     _handshakeSequence: 
      { domain: [Object],
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _callback: [Object],
        _callSite: [Error],
        _ended: false,
        _timeout: undefined,
        _idleNext: null,
        _idlePrev: null,
        _idleStart: null,
        _idleTimeout: undefined,
        _repeat: null,
        _config: [Object],
        _handshakeInitializationPacket: null },
     _handshaked: false,
     _ended: false,
     _destroyed: false,
     _queue: [ [Object], [Object] ],
     _handshakeInitializationPacket: null,
     _parser: 
      { _supportBigNumbers: false,
        _buffer: <Buffer >,
        _longPacketBuffers: [],
        _offset: 0,
        _packetEnd: null,
        _packetHeader: null,
        _packetOffset: null,
        _onError: [Function],
        _onPacket: [Function],
        _nextPacketNumber: 0,
        _encoding: 'utf-8',
        _paused: false } },
  _connectCalled: true,
  state: 'disconnected',
  threadId: null }
```

Comment: What's the outcome of `npm list`?

Comment: The full list is too long for the comments section, so here is the devDependencies from package.json:
    "cucumber": "^0.5.2",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-cli": "^0.1.13",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.11.2",
    "grunt-exec": "^0.4.6",
    "sanitize-filename": "^1.3.0",
    "mysql": "^2.8.0"

Does that give enough info?

Comment: jeah, mysql is properly in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I believe I have found a solution, so posting here for anyone else struggling in a similar manner.  Please feel free to post a better explanation of why and what is happening here if you have one!

I had not implemented the callback properly, as detailed by the cucumber.js documentation; I need to pass that to the function being called, and use it to signify when that called function has completed:

StepDefinitions.js:

```
...
   this.Given(/^I have a clean Magento database$/, function (callback) {
   //callback passed into function 
   this.connectToDatabase(callback);
...
```

world.js:

```
...
    //callback now passed into function
    this.connectToDatabase = function(callback) {
    var host = 'localhost';
    var user = 'user';
    var password = 'password';
    var database = 'magento';
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: host,
        user: user,
        password: password,
        database: database
    });

    connection.connect(function(err){
        if(err) {
            console.error("Connection error: " + err.stack);
            return;
        }
    });

    connection.query('SELECT * FROM admin_user', function (err, rows) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Query error: " + err.stack);
        } else {
            console.log(rows[0]);
        }
    });
    /*callback used to signify end of function, ensuring all actions are
     actually completed before the rest of the scenario steps are completed 
     by cucumber.js*/
    connection.end(callback);
};
....
```